# Ebay API: Get All Transactions By Seller

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to use the Ebay API to get completed transactions for a seller(s) that is using a different account from my developer account. I've looked into GetSellerTransactions and GetOrders.  Unfortunately, I am not sure if it's possible to specify a User ID different from mine.  Could you point me to working example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get transactions for a user you should be first authorized by that user.

You will need a developer account for that.

This links will guide you

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/WebHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=eBay_XML_API&file=GettingTokens-Getting_Tokens_for_Applications_with_Multiple_Users.html

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/WebHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=eBay_XML_API&file=DevAndTestApplications-Testing_Applications.html

Once you get the user token for a user you need to send them along with your developer credentials to make the getOrders API call for that particular user.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will look into your recommendations.